# Python: writing function mult(a,b) for a*b with only add/sub/neg, recursion error for testing (-a,b)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, recursion, multiplication

I have this so far - but if I test with (-a, b), python gives me a recursion error. Please help, not sure why this isn't working. All other tests work here.

```
def mult(a, b):
""" mult returns the product of two inputs
    inputs: n and m are integers
    output: result of multiplying n and m
""" 
    if b < 0:
       return -mult(a,-b)
    elif b == 0:
       return 0
    elif b == 1:
       return a
    else:
       return a + mult(a,b-1)
```

Thanks out there.

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the error. Also, the indentation of your shown code is wrong, so you should get a syntax error. Finally, the check for `b == 1` is extraneous and not needed: `b` will become zero in the next recursion step.

Comment: This code works for me, after correcting the indentation. Please show the values for which the function fails.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a limit to the number of recursions. You may just be hitting into it. See the following answer:

[What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/maximum-recursion-depth)

Comment: Yeah, typically around 1000.  What were your inputs?